# Javascript syntax alignment (moment.js)

Tags: javascript, formatting, momentjs

In working with timestamps, moment.js, and the provided example of implementation by [founddrama](https://gist.github.com/founddrama/2182389), I added the following to my html site:

```
<span id="then" data-date="Aug 22 2018 11:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var then = $('#then'),
            date = moment(new Date(then.attr('data-date'))),
            update = function(){
                       then.html(date.fromNow());
                     };

        update();
        setInterval(update, 60000);
      });

      </script>
```

The output result was successful.

I would, however, like to add multiple timestamps.

In order to successfully render, I coded in this manner:

```
<span id="then" data-date="Aug 18 2018 07:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>

<span id="then1" data-date1="Aug 3 2018 16:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var then = $('#then'),
            date = moment(new Date(then.attr('data-date'))),
            update = function(){
                       then.html(date.fromNow());
                     };

        update();
        setInterval(update, 60000);
      });

      </script>

<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var then = $('#then1'),
            date = moment(new Date(then.attr('data-date1'))),
            update = function(){
                       then.html(date.fromNow());
                     };

        update();
        setInterval(update, 60000);
      });

      </script>
```

I am looking for a clean, concise way to properly group the javascript code, and place within one script block, instead of two.

Comment: Simply use [class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of [id](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (the jQuery doc was the best guide I've found rapidly).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Vincenzo, but your response did not solve... Cheers, mate!

Answer (score 0):

This will find all DOM elements with the class then and then find each of their data-date attributes and set their inner HTML to a moment.js object.

```
<span class="then" data-date="Aug 22 2018 11:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>
<span class="then" data-date="July 15 2018 9:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dates = $('.then');
  $.each(dates, function(){
    var date = moment(new Date($(this).attr('data-date')))
    $(this).html(date.fromNow());
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Steven!  Your code nugget worked beautifully.. Cheers! :)

Comment: How would I properly inject the update function and the update();
        setInterval(update, 60000) with your code?

Comment: You can wrap the interval around the code above like this:   
    `$.each(dates, function(){
        var date = moment(new Date($(this).attr('data-date')))
        $(this).html(date.fromNow());`
      })
    }, 60000);`

Answer (score 0):

First provide the class name to span elements. 
Then parse to each span elements.
Make data attribute common i.e. data-date and not different for each span.
Then parse through all the span and append the html.

```
<span class="then" data-date="Aug 18 2018 07:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>

<span class="then" data-date="Aug 3 2018 16:33:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"></span>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.then').each(function(i) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var date = moment(new Date($this.attr('data-date')));
      var update = function() {
         $this.html(date.fromNow());
      };
      update();
      setInterval(update, 60000);
    });

   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, ExeZ10!  I truly appreciate your expertise (right along with Steven from above)..  Works perfectly!  :)

Comment: You may wish to fix your typo, though.. $this.html(date.fronNow()); *****fron***** Just in case someone decides to copy and paste..  Cheers, my friend!